# Rethinkdb and GraphQL?

Tags: rethinkdb, graphql, graphql-js

I'm having trouble resolving my graphQL fields with rethinkdb queries. I have a feeling it's to do with javascript scope but I've tried almost every combination. This is what I have at the moment.

```
var connection = null;

r.connect({host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }, function(err, conn){
    if(err) throw err;
    connection = conn;
});

var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    node: nodeField,
    viewer: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: () => ( r.db("test")
                          .table("authors")
                          .get("f433f6f6-f843-4636-a1d3-eb34b89aec67")
                          .getField("name")
      ),
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: The `resolve` function should return a promise in case of an asynchronous operation. You can also use async-await in your resolve function.

Comment: Any resolution on this? Getting ready to head down a similar path with rethinkdb / graphql.

Comment: The problem was the missing `run(conn)` function at the end of the db request.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same problem until I solve it using Promises. This is my schema:

```
const db = require('../db');

const {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
} = require('graphql');

const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQuery',
  fields:{
    usersCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: () => {
        return db.getUsers().then((result) =>{
          return result.length
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

const mySchema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: queryType
});

module.exports = mySchema;
```

db.js

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var r =require('rethinkdb');

const dbConfig = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 28015,
    db: 'test'
};

const connect = ()  => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    r.connect({
      host: dbConfig.host,
      port: dbConfig.port
    }).then((connection)=>{
      resolve(connection);
    }).catch((e) =>{
      reject(e);
    });
  })
};

const getUsers = () => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => {
    connect().then( (connection) => {
      r.db('test').table('users').run(connection).then((cursor) => {
         return cursor.toArray()
       }).then( (result) => {
          resolve(result);
       }).then(() => {
           connection.close();
       }).catch((err) => {
          connection.close();
          reject(err);
       });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Connection error: ", error);
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

exports.getUsers = getUsers;
```

I hope this can help. You can find a full working example here: https://github.com/luiscript/graphql-rethinkdb-x

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with GraphQL. Have you tried adding `.run()` at the end of your RethinkDB query? Without `run()` the query does not get sent to the DB.

Comment: @helfer It may help to add to the answer why `run()`  needs to be added to the resolve function.

Comment: `run()` has to be added at the end of the RethinkDB query, not the resolve function. Without `run()`, the query is just composed, but not sent to the DB.

Comment: oops.. I should have been careful. I actually meant "at the end of query" in the resolve function. Thanks!

Comment: And pass a connection variable to it, right? The trouble is, do I have to do `r.connect({host: x, post: y}, (err, conn) => { // What I want to return })` in each resolve function? Seems redundant. Could I not make the connection variable global, or be able to export/import it? btw, excuse the formatting I don't like stack overflow's editing window at all